# Redeclaration of a variable in an inner scope affects the variable outside the scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, variable-assignment, declaration

The following javascript code

```
var variable = 1
console.log(variable)
{
    var variable = 2
}
console.log(variable)
```

gives the output

```
1
2
```

Given the way scopes work in other programming languages I find this very unintuitive. The redeclaration of *variable* inside the scope shouldn't affect the value of the *variable* outside the scope.

I tested this on Firefox and Chromium. Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior of javascript?

As a reference, this is what happens in other programming languages:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int variable=1;
    printf("%i\n",variable);
    {
        int variable=2;
    }
    printf("%i\n",variable);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1
1
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have block scope. At least, not recently (see the answer). So both your declarations are actually in the same scope and there's no shadowing happening in your snippet like there is in c. Which is why you see the `(function() {...})();` pattern all over the place in JS.

Comment: Thanks, I now updated my knowledge using [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable]

Comment: This resource is a very nice explanation of the different scopes in javascript: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript#500459

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you could use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let), which respects block scope

> The **`let`** statement declares a block scope local variable, optionally initializing it to a value.

instead of `var` declaration.

```js
var variable = 1;
console.log(variable);
{
    let variable = 2;
}
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: Did you mean to say 'instead of var declaration, which doesn't respect block scope' ?